# jQuery fade in on one <li>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm creating a task manager app that creates a new **li** whenever the user adds an item. However, fadeIn() is triggering for every li on the page whenever a new item is created. Any help on getting fadeIn() to only fade in new items added?

```
$('form').submit(function() {

  // Grab input and set it to lowercase
  var input = $('.listInput').val().toLowerCase();

  // Fade in li whenever an item is added
  $('#list').append('<li>' + input + '</li>').hide().fadeIn(500);

  // Remove text from input
  $('.listInput').val('');

  return false;

});
```

[image: Example]

Comment: try: `$('<li>' + input + '</li>').hide().fadeIn(500).appendTo('#list');`

Comment: `$('#list').append` will return `#list` element..

Comment: `$('#list').append($('<li>' + input + '</li>').hide().fadeIn(500));`.. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/k2vux27h/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this by creating the element first, then appending it, and fading it in.  I also prefer using css to make it initially hidden rather than jQuery `hide()`:

```js
$('form').submit(function() {

  // Grab input and set it to lowercase
  var input = $('.listInput').val().toLowerCase();

  // Create new element first
  var li = $('<li style="display:none">' + input + '</li>');

  // Fade in li whenever an item is added
  $('#list').append(li);
  li.fadeIn(500);

  // Remove text from input
  $('.listInput').val('');

  return false;

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <ul id="list">
    <li>abc</li>
    <li>def</li>
  </ul>
  <input type="text" class="listInput" />
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: @Rayon - That's true.  I do this often when I need to further manipulate the element.  I was thinking that this method illustrates a concept the OP might find useful.

Comment: Ah, that's a good point! Still wrapping my head around jQuery, so setting the visibility in CSS is a great idea.

Answer (score 1):

`$('<li>' + input + '</li>').hide().fadeIn(500).appendTo('#list');` will do. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k2vux27h/).

Comment: It always amazes me how I can spend an hour trying to figure out something and then I find out the answer is simple. Thank you!